# Transmission using SPI in AVR

Tags: avr, spi

When will SPIF bit in SPSR will reset after transmission of data
Suppose

```
void SPITransmit(uint8_t data)
{
    SPDR = data;
   while(!(SPSR & (1<<SPIF)));
 }
```

After transmission SPIF will set and how to reset this bit for  reception.

Answer (score 1):

With SPI, you don't get to choose whether you are sending or transmitting, you do both at the same time.  So there is no need to "reset SPIF for reception".  I believe the received data is available in the `SPDR` register after your loop terminates, but you should read the datasheet for your particular AVR to make sure.

Here is a function you could use to transmit and receive at the same time:

```
uint8_t SPITransmit(uint8_t data)
{
  SPDR = data;
  while(!(SPSR & (1<<SPIF)));
  return SPDR;
}
```

Comment: rx vs tx is specific to the spi controller design, the AVRs might work this way (and from what I remember do) but that is not necessarily universal, nor required (the mosi can be fixed for a read period and not have to be driven by a shift register, likeise miso can be discarded in the logic).  All depends on the design.